# What is the proper way of disposing a QMessageBox instance?

Tags: qt

given this code:

```
void FooBar::ProcessExitHandler(QProcess* someProcess, QString logsPath)
{
    if (clientProcess->exitCode() != 0)
    {
        QMessageBox* dialog = new QMessageBox();
        dialog->setText("bye bye");
        dialog->setStandardButtons(0);

        QObject::connect(dialog, &QMessageBox::finished, [this](int) { 
            if (mMainWindow->AutoCloseCheckBoxChecked())
            {
                delete dialog; //TODO: need to confirm what is the correct way 
                this->quit();
            }
        });

        dialog->show();
        dialog->activateWindow();
    }
    else
    {
        if (mMainWindow->AutoCloseCheckBoxChecked())
        {
            delete dialog; //TODO: need to confirm what is the correct way 
            this->quit();
        }
    }
}
```

Is calling `delete dialog` like that correct? Is there a more QT idiomatic way of doing this?

Also, something that has caused me confusion is the idea (from the docs) that I should be passing a `parent` to the constructor of the message box. Then I would get automatic memory management, right? Is that the QT style I should shoot for?

I'm aware that since the app is exiting anyway, the leak "doesn't matter", but I want to do the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

The right way is to use [`setAttribute`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setAttribute)

```
 QMessageBox* dialog = new QMessageBox();
 dialog->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
```

By setting the attribute `WA_DeleteOnClose`, the destructor will be called at the right moment.

When you manually call `delete`, the pointer will keep its value (the address) although it isn't valid anymore. If for some reason you were to reuse that pointer again, the app would crash.

> \warning Deleting a QObject while pending events are waiting to  be
>   delivered can cause a crash. You must not delete the QObject  directly
>   if it exists in a different thread than the one currently  executing.
>   Use deleteLater() instead, which will cause the event  loop to delete
>   the object after all pending events have been  delivered to it.
>   https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/kernel/qobject.cpp.html#881

Comment: Or we can use dialog->deleteLater() and let the Qt event system do the cleanup.